# Realization of the Static links

Tags: application-development, libraries, shared-library

I know about Static and Dynamic links. but I have a problem with static link:

Static link is a part of application and it compile with application isn't it?

But why are there in here?
They should be a part of applications!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static libraries are likely there because you have installed one or more of the C development packages - to see exactly which, you can query the package database e.g.

```
$ dpkg -S libm.a
libc6-dev-i386: /usr/lib32/libm.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
libc6-dev-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libm.a
```